# Ignoring BGRT Invalid status 0 (expected 1)

Tags: 15.10

From Frank

I have a new laptop – Hp Pavilion AMD A8 and  AMD Radeon graphics and running Ubuntu 15.04, as a unique system (I throw away Win 8.1)

Updating to 15.10 from DVD (or from USB stick) I see the message on the screen:

```
0.054884  Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
```

Every thing freezes, no access anymore to the system and the possible way to get out is shutting down the computer.

Is there anybody who can help?

In 15.04  :  via the terminal following info:

```
frank@frank-Pavilion:~$ sudo dmesg | grep BGRT
[sudo] password for frank: 
[    0.000000] ACPI: BGRT 0x000000006CF029C0 000038 (v01 HPQOEM 226B     01072009 HP   00010013)
[    0.048422] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
frank@frank-Pavilion:~$
```

Is there a way to eliminate BGRT?

Following info  / the kernel 4.1.0-3 works fine
                             the kernel 4.2.0-16 blocks the system

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

BGRT is the ACPI Boot Graphics Resource Table.  The error you see is because the status value in the table is zero, hence bit 0 (the display bit) is not turned on, so the boot graphic is not being displayed. The BGRT message is just reporting that this is disabled on your machine, and it is not a fatal error.

For more details, see the Linux driver: arch/x86/platform/efi/efi-bgrt.c, and ACPI BGRT description in the ACPI specification, http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/ACPI_6.0.pdf, section 5.2.22.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the log, that's not an error, that's a warning.

```
Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
```

The freeze has another reason. Wait for the next upgrade of the official kernel for Ubuntu 15.10 (currently `4.2.0.16.18`) or your custom kernel `4.1.0-3`.

Comment: From Frank  -- thanks for the quick response --  but the latest is yust the point. The dvd with ubuntu 15.10 has the 4.2.0.16 kernel and blocks the system for loading!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a sentence.

Comment: The new kernel 4.2.0.17 .. don't start - just the same problem